# Windows Drives - Access & Manipilate Entries

Tags: c#, windows

Here is a screen shot. There are some Drives, One DVDisk Drive, One Virtual-Drive (alcohol 120%), One Network Location.

[image]

I want to **Where**&**How** Windows stores them, lets say, listing of these drives.  And how much I can change this listing using **C#**.

Comment: Have you done any research so far?

Comment: i have been using a Library Known as Dokan to Display Virtual Drives and Remote Storages as Virtual Drives, i was thinking of messing with the Windows Listings itself and experiment with what i can do, i don't exactly know where to start studying about the subject

Comment: What would you like to change in the listing ? In other words: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: make remote storage appear as local HDDs, make ROMs appear as normal Drives, create\edit categories in My Computer that is Hard Disk Drives, Devices with Removable Storage, Network Location, Add Custom Context Menus (that i think is done via Shell Name Extensions), Map Virtual Drives out of Folders, have some Program to do all that dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Is this, what you are looking for? `DriveInfo.GetDrives();`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx

Comment: yes that can be done, but where is Windows getting the list from, is it maintaining registry entries or what

Comment: The list of local drives comes from the kernel drive manager. You can use `diskpart` or the Disk Management MMC snap-in to manipulate local drives. Remote drives come from the network redirector.